# Comparing the Output of Functions Correctly

Tags: python

I've written the base of a Rock-Scissor-Paper game in Python 2.7, as follows:

```
  1 #!/bin/py
  2 #Python 2.7.6
  3 from random import choice
  4 
  5 moves = ["r", "p", "s"] # Possible moves  
  6 winning_combos = {("r", "s"), ("s", "p"), ("p", "r")} # Winning   outcomes 
  7 
  8 def human():
  9         print
 10         print "R: Rock    P: Paper    S: Scissor"
 11         print
 12         human_move = raw_input("Enter your choice: ").lower()
 13         return human_move
 14 ()
 15 
 16 def bot():
 17         bot_move = choice(moves)
 18         return bot_move
 19 ()
 20 
 21 while True:
 22         human(), bot()
 23         if human() == bot():
 24                 print "Grr... a tie!"
 25         elif (human(), bot()) in winning_combos:
 26                 print "Woo-hoo! You win this round, human"
 27         else:
 28                 print "Bwahahaha! The almighty bot wins!"
```

.

My question is how, if at all, can I compare the results of the human() and bot() functions as I am trying to do in line 25? When this program runs as is, I am prompted to enter input twice before the comparison is done.

I can write this program in a different way to produce an acceptable result, so I am not looking to rewrite the program. I'm specifically, although perhaps not effectively, asking about how to tweak this program as is (I'm fairly new to Python), as well as understand what I have done incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: "How can I...." is always an open-ended question and hard to answer.  Can you instead say what concrete result you hoped to achieve, and what error (or what wrong result) you got in place of the expected result?

Comment: Thank you, jez. Sorry for the open-ended nature of the question. @Jerome looks to have understood the error of my ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're calling `human` and `bot` each time you need to access the value. Store the results in variables, something like this:

```
while True:
        human_move, bot_move = human(), bot()
        if human_move == bot_move:
                print "Grr... a tie!"
        elif (human_move, bot_move) in winning_combos:
                print "Woo-hoo! You win this round, human"
        else:
                print "Bwahahaha! The almighty bot wins!"
```

Comment: Doh! I tried originally to do this: `human, bot = human(), bot()` and received an error related to strings, but your suggestion works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: You were erasing your functions by naming the variables with the same name...: `human = human()` will work once, but then `human` is not a function anymore.